# .each() is showing socket.io data, not the elements I'm trying to iterate through

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I'm trying to iterate through a series of DIVs, like so:

```
$(".div_class").each(() => {
  console.log($(this))

  // something happens here
})
```

However, the `$(this)` being logged to the console is not the DOM element I'm trying to access. Instead, I'm getting a load of socket.io information:

```
S.fn.init [Socket]
  0: Socket {receiveBuffer: Array(0), sendBuffer: Array(0), ids: 0, acks: 
  {…}, flags: {…}, …}
  length: 1
  [[Prototype]]: Object(0)
```

(and so on and so forth)

Does anyone know why this might be, and how I might be able to get the properties of the elements I'm looping through/trying to access?

Comment: When using arrow syntax, "this" is the outer context, not the inner context. You have nothing in your each parameter: `.each((element) => { })`.

Comment: Because fat arrows work like that. function() } and () => {} are not really interchangeable. They behave differently which you just found out.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - appreciate it.